# Can you Remote Debug with a Amazon Phone? (LG X-Charge)

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-studio, remote-debugging

I want to debug my website on mobile Chrome. I turned on Dev mode and USB debugging on my phone. My machines has RSA key fingerprint and authorization to connect to my phone but cannot still see my  phone in Chrome's remote device list.

I have Java Runtime Environment and Android SDK (not, Android Studio), and ADB server is running. Why does not my machine see my phone?

Comment: what does the command **adb devices** shows you?

Comment: @alexscmar On my machine right? None :( Thanks for your response!

Comment: Don't have Chrome Remote Debugging and the SDK adb server running at the same time, Chrome I believe has its own adb server so they may conflict.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @alexscmar Ubuntu 18.04 :)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I killed the server and still it is not working :( Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to add your device to **51-android.rules** file?
(/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules)

Comment: @alexscmar Thank you! I was able to find that my phone was connected as a media device while looking at 51-android.rules. Now, it shows up! You helped me a lot! Thanks!

Comment: @Heuyie That would be my next tip to you to check the USB mode. Glad I've helped. Have a nice debug :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was connection mode between my machine and my phone. My phone was connected as a media device, so I changed its connection to "Just charging."